# Grep lines starting with 1, but not 10, 11, 100 etc

Tags: linux, grep, numeric-data

I have a file of genomic data with tag counts, I want to know how many are represented once:

```
$ grep "^1" file |wc -l
```

includes all lines beginning with 1, so it includes tags represented 10 times, 11, times, 100 times, 1245 times, etc. How do I do this?

```
Current format
79      TGCAG.....
1       TGCAG.....
1257    TGCAG.....
1       TGCAG......
```

I only want the lines that are:

```
1       TGCAG.....
```

So it cannot include the lines beginning with 1257. **NOTE:** The file above is tab delimited.

Comment: By the way, based on you example here, you might be interested in our sister site, [bioinformatics.se].

Comment: I have erred on the side of retracting my own close vote, because the answers on the linked question which most convince me, are those which anticipate the possibility of `-`, and the current such answers either require PCRE (which is not required here), or assume ASCII space character as a delimiter, not a tab character.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '$1 == "1" { print; x++ } END { print x, "total matches" }' inputfile
```

Comment: Nice touch w/ the total!

Comment: Plus can use `awk '{print $1}' <inputfile|sort -n|uniq -c` get a summary of the tag count frequencies.

Comment: No need to indirect `inputfile` with `<`, but yes indeed.

Answer (score 27):

#### The question in the body

Select lines that start with a `1` and are followed by an space

```
grep -c '^1\s'          file
grep -c '^1[[:space:]]' file
```

That will also give the count of lines (without needing the call to wc)

#### The question in the title

A `1` **not** followed by another number (or nothing):

```
grep -cE '^1([^0-9]|$)' file
```

But both solutions above have some interesting issues, keep reading.

---

In the body of the question the user claim that the file is "tab delimited".

## Delimiter

#### tab

A line starting with a `1` followed by a tab (an actual tab in the command). This fails if the delimiter is an space (or any other, or none):

```
grep '^1    ' file
```

#### space

A line starting with a `1` followed by a space (an actual space in the command). This fails if the delimiter is any other or none.:

```
grep '^1 ' file
```

#### tab or space

```
grep '^1(   | )' file
grep '^1[[:blank:]]' file
```

#### whitespace

A more flexible option is to include several space (horizontal and vertical) characters. The `[:space:]` character class set is composed of  (space), `\t` (horizontal tab), `\r` (carriage return),`\n`(newline), `\v` (vertical tab) and `\f` (form feed). But grep can not match a newline (it is an internal limitation that could only be avoided with the `-z` option). It is possible to use it as a description on the delimiter. It is also possible, and shorter, to use the GNU available shorthand of `\s`:

```
grep -c '^1[[:space:]]` file
grep -c '^1\s'          file
```

But this option will fail if the delimiter is something like a colon `:` or any other punctuation character (or any letter).

## Boundary

Or, we can use the transition from a digit to a "not a digit" boundary, well, actually "a character not in `[_[:alnum:]]` (`_a-zA-Z0-9`)":

```
grep -c  '^1\b' file       # portable but not POSIX.
grep -c  '^1\>' file       # portable but not POSIX.
grep -wc '^1'   file       # portable but not POSIX.
grep -c  '^1\W' file       # portable but not POSIX (not match only a `1`) (not underscore in BSD).
```

This will accept as valid lines that start with a 1 and are followed by some punctuation character.

Comment: There is no way that the lines presented by the user: `1 TGCAG…`  will contain **only** a `1` (that is: without genomic data). But, anyway, a viable solution also added. @StéphaneChazelas

Answer (score 19):

Sounds like you just want this:

```
$ grep '^1\b' a
1        TGCAG.....
1        TGCAG......
```

For the counting portion of this:

```
$ grep -c '^1\b' file
2
```

Answer (score 14):

Either of these will pick out lines with a `1` in the first column

```
awk '$1 == 1'
grep -w '^1'
```

These can both can be extended so you don't even need the `wc` to count the lines

```
awk '$1==1 { x++ } END { print x }'
grep -cw '^1'
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `grep`:

```
grep -c '^1\s' file
```

This will match any line starting with a 1 immediately followed by whitespace and provide a count of those lines (eliminating the need for `wc -l`)

---

```
$ cat input
79       TGCAG.....
1        TGCAG.....
1257     TGCAG.....
1        TGCAG......
$ grep -Ec '^1\s' input
2
```

Answer (score 3):

Good answers here, but assuming that not every line ends in a space (like if you've got some that actually make it to your "="), you can use this:

```
 grep -c "^1[^0-9]" file
```

It basically matches for any line that begins with one, followed by a non-digit, including white space. A little more verbose, but also more foolproof. (Though it's worth noting that there's nothing here for the null condition of just-one-on-the-line, it isn't end-of-line sensitive.)

Comment: Note that it disallows lines consisting _only_ of `1`. If that's not desired, use e.g. `^1($|[^0-9])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below line also:

```
$ awk -F' ' '{if($1=="1") print $0}' <your file name> | wc -l
```

The parameter `-F` makes the field separator a whitespace.
If the first field's value is '1', its line will be printed.